# CMD command not running in console

Tags: c#, console, cmd

I have some code that runs a cmd command in C# which works really well in a WinForm but when running this in a console app it doesn't work. I am a bit stuck as to why this is, I tried adding Windows.Forms as a reference and added the `using` to the code but this didn't work either. The only other thing I can think of is that because it is running as a console it can't run another console window on top of this?

Any help is appreciated.

```
ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process console = Process.Start(cmd);
console.StandardInput.WriteLine("command to run");
```

Comment: Wow, all this to create a folder? How about the [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) method?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The md command was just as an example where I would put the command, I see your point, edited!

Comment: do you absolutely need `cmd.exe` to execute your commands? can't you execute them directly using `Process.Start`?

Comment: Yeah and I don't like the console window appearing which this code stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will perform any console command you want and output the console text in your current window, everything after while(true) is just as example:

```
        ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        Process console = Process.Start(cmd);

        while(true)
            console.StandardInput.WriteLine("pause");
```

If you don't want any console output then set CreateNoWindow to true. Also this code works inside a console application using System.Diagnostics

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, thats just what I was looking for, +1. Thank you very much!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It simply passes the command, but nothing happens behind the scene.