# CommandPrompt command not run after release the build C# application

Tags: c#, cmd

I am using a command of a Command Prompt in my application. Application able to run and execute that command of a Command Prompt when I run my application using Visual Studio while debugging but when I take my application's executable file(.exe) and save in my pc drive and then run the file it skips the Command Prompt Command. I research for the topic and get this :
[CMD command not running in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268273/cmd-command-not-running-in-console)
but no success.

My code :

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = sentencesList;    
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C findstr /V /I \"" + ListOfSomeWords + "\" " + sentencesList+ ">" + filteredList;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
process.Dispose();
```

Command remove the sentence/line from a text file(sentenceList) which contains a word(ListOfSomeWords) and make a another text file(filteredList) which contains only those line which not contains any of word specify in ListOfSomeWords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping `filteredList` with quotes. If it contains a space, then it could not be interpreted correctly by cmd.exe .

Also make sure that you are setting WorkingDirectory  to an existing directory path(variable name file_path looks suspicious).